# How is private code accessed in nodejs modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side

How are private functions and data of modules accessed after loading the module?

I know that the `require` function loads the module and returns the `module.exports` object which contains some public objects or functions, but how are the other '*private*' parts of the code in the module accessed? where is it located in the memory?

Comment: To be clear, you're wondering how the private functions / data in the module is used **in the module**, right? You can't use it from outside the module, that's why we call them "private."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - Code in NodeJS modules can continue to access the non-exported things they define within the modules because they and the functions they define *close over* that data.

Details:

NodeJS modules are effectively big functions that get *called* by NodeJS when you `require` them. (They're only called **once**, regardless of how many times they're `require`d.) A function call in JavaScript sets up an *execution context* and any functions created *within* that context *close over* the context (they have an enduring reference to it and its contents). The execution context survives in memory as long as anything has a reference to it, even after the "function" has returned. The functions created within the execution context are "*closures*".

So say you have a module `foo`:

```
var privateData = Math.random();
function publicFunction() {
    console.log("The private data is " + privateData);
}
module.exports.publicFunction = publicFunction;
```

and you `require` it:

```
var foo = require("foo");
foo.publicFunction(); // Displays the random number
```

That's analogous to having a function that returns an object:

```
function fooModule() {
    var privateData = Math.random();
    function publicFunction() {
        console.log("The private data is " + privateData);
    }
    return {
        publicFunction: publicFunction
    };
}
```

that you call:

```
var foo = fooModule();
foo.publicFunction(); // Displays the random number
```

The same mechanism is at work in both places.

More to explore:

- [*How do JavaScript closures work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)
- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) (on my blog)

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The consumer of a module can only interact with its API, a.k.a. what it *exports*.  You cannot access its private functions and state directly.  That would violate encapsulation.

The module itself can do it for you.  Whatever functions are exported by a given module can interact with anything in that module.

If you come from a Java or C# world, think of it like public/private methods on a class.  In a node module, everything is "private" unless it is exported.